# How can I get internal signals to testbench in VHDL 97 and ISim?

Tags: vhdl, simulation, test-bench

I'm working in a testbench with VHDL 97 and Xilinx ISim, and I'm looking for a way to know the value of a UUT internal signal (like spy function in Modelsim) from code instead of waveform.

I know that I can do easily with VHDL-2008 and `alias` but does someone know any alternative?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:  Declare a global signal in a package

```
package SpyOnMySigPkg is
  -- synthesis translate_off 
  signal GlobalMySig : std_logic ; 
  -- synthesis translate_on 
end package SpyOnMySigPkg ;
```

Step 2:  Reference the package and assign to the global signal in your design:

```
use work.SpyOnMySigPkg.all ;
entity MyDesign is 
....
    -- synthesis translate_off 
    GlobalMySig <= MySig ; 
    -- synthesis translate_on
```

Step 3:  Reference the package and read the signal in your testbench:

```
use work.SpyOnMySigPkg.all ;
entity tb is 
....
  process (GlobalMySig) 
  begin
    if GlobalMySig = '1' then ...
```